# What is the best way to use nested components in Angular 4 and calling a method of a parent to child and vice versa?

Tags: angular

Please help me to explain the best way to use nested components in `Angular 4` and calling a method of a parent to child and vice versa. Please explain with an example and live editor.

Thanks in advance.

I want to learn and design my own tabset or other components using angular 4 like tabset ngx-bootstrap but more in advance. I am new to angular > 2.

Here are the scenario:

1. Expose several api from a components.
2. Use that api to set/register/retrieve data/method/setting to/from component.

I want to learn to build a component as a framework using different design pattern of software.

Hence, want to grab depth knowledge in correct way from experienced about communication between different components.  I am following official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I want to learn and design my own tabset or other components using angular 4 like tabset ngx-bootstrap but more in advance. I am new to angular > 2.

Here are the scenario:

Expose several api from a components.
Use that api to set/register/retrieve data/method/setting to/from data component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have details on the first technique Lazar mentions: using @Input and @Output here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/passing-data-to-and-raising-an-event-from-a-nested-component/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Parent-child component communication can be achieved in a couple of different ways.

## Pass data from parent to child using an input

For this strategy, use an [`@Input()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) decorator in the child component and [input-binding syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions) `[]` in your template to pass data in.

If you need to intercept these property in the child, use a [setter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) for `@Input()`, or use the [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) which responds to input properties changes, named [`ngOnChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges).

## Listen for events from child from child to parent using an output

In this case, you child component will have to expose an [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) decorated as [`@Ouput()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Output); for example `@Output() foo = new EventEmitter()`. Then you will be able to listen for those events from the parent in the template using the [event-binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-statements) syntax `(foo)`.

To query a child or multiple children from the parent without children having to explicitly know about this behaviour, use [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildDecorator) and [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildrenDecorator) decorators.

## Communication via service

This is the most global case, and can be used for any kind of communication. Components do not have to be in parent-child relationship: they could be siblings, or grandchildren/grandparents. To use the same instance of a service in both component that need to communicate, you need to use [Angular's dependency injection (DI) mechanism](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection), via components' constructors.

---

You can read more about these types of component communication in the official guide [Component interaction in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). You can find a lot of examples there, including on the links I've linked through the answer.